# Как проверить большой URL с помощью isset и $_GET?

Tags: php

я знаю как проверить короткий URL вроде такого **shop/?filter_cat_1=78**,
с помощью `if (isset($_GET['filter_cat_1']))`, но как проверить URL если там задано несколько **filter_cat_1, filter_cat_2**. Вроде такого **shop/?filter_cat_1=78&filter_cat_2=70**. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Точно так же. `if (isset() || isset() || isset())`. Если нужно чтобы все были установлены одновременно - то `if (isset($var1, $var2, $var3))`. Дальше идут оптимизации - список доступных ключей и цикл по ним, и какие-нибудь еще хитрости.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял , то для начала нужно получить список ключей $_GET запроса, что то вроде этого

```
$result = "";

if (isset($_GET) && array_keys($_GET)) {
     foreach (array_keys($_GET) as $item) {
         // echo $item;
         // Получаем filter_cat_1,filter_cat_2
         //Далее уже выполняем проверку 
        
          if($_GET[$item] == 78){
              $result = $item . " Равен 78";
          }
     }
}
echo $result; // если условие совпало 78, то получим 'filter_cat_1 равен 78' если нет, то пустую строку
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. у меня вопрос как проверить по id? Мне нужно. если в URL стоит значение 76 filter_cat_list_1=76, то должен отображаться 76. У меня почему-то по умолчанию выводиться  id 78, когда в URL указано 76. Как решить проблему? Вот мой код:  if (isset($_GET['filter_cat_list_1']) == 78) {  echo "id 78"; } elseif (isset($_GET['filter_cat_list_1']) == 76) { echo "id 76"; }

Comment: А полностью URL (после домена) можно увидеть?

Comment: /shop/?filter_cat_list_1=76

Comment: Для сравнения не нужно использовать isset используйте просто if($_GET['filter_cat_list_1'] == 78) или 76. isset лишь проверяет существование и выдаст только  true  или false

Comment: Так как все ключи в GET - запросе уже имеют проверку -  php  не будет ругаться на отсутствие того или иного параметра. Но можете для "успокоения" использовать что то вроде if(isset($_GET['filter_cat_list_1']) && $_GET['filter_cat_list_1'] == 78)